# What is the current status of support for optimus graphics cards?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia-optimus

I will make a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 on my machine in a bit.

Will I have to install optimus / will the system auto-install it / is there a better option than optimus available at this time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimus is supported in Ubuntu and will work when you install the closed source NVIDIA drivers. You'll have a tab (PRIME profiles) in the Nvidia settings screen where you can switch between the Intel or Nvidia card. Only downside is that you need to log out and back in again in order to apply the changes. It is not dynamic, as in Windows.

Comment: ended up going with prime and basically shutting the nvidia card down - it was not needed anyway. thanks.

Comment: No problem! I heard that there also is a prime indicator available for Ubuntu that makes switching a bit less of a hassle (although logging out is still required..). Haven't used it yet but you might want to look into it!

Comment: Yes, I went with it and makes things a bit quicker plus it lets you know which card you are using. Just saying it here in case it helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Nvidia Website](http://www.nvidia.in/object/optimus_technology.html).

It is said that Optimus Technology requires Windows 7 or higher.

[image: OT]

But there is a support to Optimus Technology in Ubuntu called [Bumblebee.](http://bumblebee-project.org/)

And yes, you have to download it externally.